# Why don't we have more registers in microprocessors?

Tags: microprocessor

Registers are theoretically not required; all microprocessors would still work without registers. But this seemingly trivial addition has helped make microprocessors more efficient.

Why can't we have more registers to further extract benefit from them? They are just *memory on chip* and one can imagine not very difficult to add? What factor influenced the number of registers to be what they are now and not, say 10x more?

Comment: Legacy. Lots of it.

Comment: I did not get what yo mean. Registers are totally required to get a uP work. Infact, #1 condition to start with.

Comment: @Alper91 Many architectures, hypothetical and real, do not have registers, and it's not at all necessary. It's simply a useful optimization.

Comment: In 8 bit PICs, all the RAM is registers. For example the PIC16F18877 has 4K of RAM which is accessed via 64 banks, each with 80 file registers.

Comment: Hmm. No one has mentioned the Sparc. The largest implementation could have 520 registers in it (32 windows times 16 registers, + 8 globals.) I sure remember them.

Comment: I think the number of bits in the instruction that you need to specify the register is a big problem. If you have 1024 registers, then you need at least 30 bits for every arithmetic instruction - unless you add other constraints like "all 3 registers must be from the same group of 32 (in which case you need 20 bits).

Comment: The "more memory on chip" is implemented as L1 cache.

Comment: @pjc50: Yeah. But that L1, which used to be just 3X slower than the cpu back in the P2 days, is now still slower as the cpu has clocked up faster. Just doesn't come close to the cpu speed. Mostly "hurry up and wait" even for the L1. L1 is not a register.

Comment: @pipe - actually pretty much any practical design does require "registers" in the schematic sense, as even if you build a stack machine or something like that, you have to have a place to hold the arguments to the ALU, or else the outputs - most memories don't have three access ports.  And a stack machine needs a *stack pointer* which is... a register!   And lets not mention pipeline registers.  You can hide the use of such "registers" from the programmer, but you still need some, and probably nearly as many as a primitive register machine has.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sure, but as long as they are not exposed through the ISA, it's simply an implementation detail. Somewhat pointless argument though, since we don't know what OP means by _register_.

Comment: Do note that a processor can have more registers than what its architecture demands. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming

Comment: Some of the older microprocessors used multiple registers to hold each memory address - for example, I've read of 8-bit processors with 1 MB of memory.

Answer (score 38):

There are several factors:

- high performance micro-architectures use register renaming.  That is, the number of physical registers is higher than the number of architecturally visible registers and they are able to track independent uses of them.
- doubling the number of registers does not double the performance.  ISTR (from *Computer architecture, A Quantitative Approach*) that going from 16 to 32 registers brings something like a 10% improvement assuming that the increase has no adverse effect (which is a very optimistic assumption).
- architecturally visible registers have costs.  For instance:

  - Increasing their number increases the number of bits taken in the instruction format to indicate which register is being acted on (doubling the number of register implies to have one more bit per register in the format, thus preventing to use those bits for other usages or forcing a longer instruction size).
  - Increasing the number of architectural registers increases the context switching cost (as they must be saved and restored on context switch).

Comment: I'd wager that the performance improvement of 16 to 32 registers depends totally on the optimization potential of the compiler in question. In assembler, having access to double the number of registers (in x64 architecture) can vastly improve performance - but only for niche roles, and only if they are actually used.

Comment: @rdtsc: going from 8 to 16 architectural registers gives big improvements in the amount of spills/reloads for typical code, [according to data from simulations in a paper linked from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466981/why-does-arm-have-16-registers).  It affects code size, instruction count, and how important low-latency store-forwarding is.  16->32 is a much smaller effect.  AFAICT, 16 architectural registers is a good choice for hardware with register renaming to remove WAR and WAW hazards.

Comment: However, Intel's AVX512 adds 16 more vector regs, for a total of 32.  (As well as doubling their width to 64 bytes, a full cache line).  Hiding the latency from high throughput high latency FP operations can take a lot of registers.  e.g. Intel Haswell has 5c lat, one per 0.5c throughput FMA, so you need 10 vector accumulators to saturate the FMA execution units for a reduction (e.g. dot product, or summing an array, where the FMA is part of a loop-carried dependency).  x86-64 only has 16 vector regs.  But remember, integer ops, esp. on GP regs, rarely have more than 1c latency.

Comment: The trade-off is different for integer, FP and vector registers.  For instance lazy save/restore of integer registers does not make sense, doing it for vector one is a far better bet.  And vector ISA have often more registers than integer one (AltiVec has at least up to 128, ISTR having read about a 256 one for Sparc but can't find a reference now).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltiVec has thirty-two 128b vector regs.  I got curious about SPARC and looked up how its register-window stuff worked for context switches.  It has 32 registers visible at once, but uses a sliding window onto a larger register file.  It sounds [from this simplified version](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~jer/courses/os/lecnotes/lec11.html) like the OS needs to know the size of the whole sliding-window register file to save/restore it, because even though the window-slide instructions provide memory for saving/restore regs if needed, it's done by trapping to the OS.

Comment: But yes, it's normal that the tradeoffs are different kinds of registers.  You mentioned lazy save/restore; Intel has gone beyond the normal meaning of that, and added [the XSAVEOPT instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XSAVEOPT.html) that saves whole register sets (e.g. all the vector regs) *in an optimized format*.  It's allowed to skip saving registers that haven't been modified (and records this in opaque metadata in the save area that's allowed to vary depending on microarchitecture).  The OS queries (once at startup) the size of memory that it needs to reserve for XSAVEOPT.

Comment: +1 for mentioning context switch cost, a huge cost which is usually overlooked/ignored (especially by Intel with their ever-growing AVX register file ruining context-switch times).

Comment: I'd like to suggest a tiny formatting improvement. I think the last bullet point about instruction size, and context switch cost are really two different points, and so may be better formatted as two bullets. Also, maybe worth considering the first part about instruction size can be made concrete w.r.t. the question, 10x more registers would require about 3.3 more bits in the instruction (16x more registers would be 4 bits more), and hence for a 3 address machine, would need 12 bits bigger instructions, a 32 bit instruction would need to become a 44 bit instruction. Just a thought

Answer (score 16):

While registers and RAM are both memory, they are accessed in different ways, to reflect the cost (in chip area, or of hidden clock cycles) of accesssing them.

Registers are tightly bound to the ALU, and can take many roles of data sources, sinks, modifiers etc. They therefore need a wealth of wide multiplexed connections. In some architectures we can write R1 <= R2 + R3, and that is exactly what happens in a single clock cycle. Each register is directly addressed in the op code, this addressing is a very limited resource.

As registers are expensive to implement, the number is usually limited to the order of 10/20 in most architectures.

RAM is loosely bound to the CPU, usually being channelled through a single shared connection. This makes it much much cheaper to implement a large amount of RAM. RAM addresses generally come from a register-stored address, so don't consume significant instruction width.

SPARC is an interesting architecture, with 72 to 640 64 bit registers, with a 32 register context that can be shifted with overlaps for fast subroutine calls with parameter passing. You tend not to find them in PCs and servers where cost matters, like in 99.999% of applications.

Comment: Another aspect is you have to save/restore registers during a context switch.  More registers, more time.

Comment: I would note that the old TMS9900 kept all its working registers in external memory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS9900

Comment: I had qualified 'invariably' with (excepting a few tweaks) but took it out to simplify it. Perhaps I'll just change it to 'generally'. Basically if you can find and understand the exceptions, you don't need me to point them out. If you're niave enough to be misled, then it doesn't matter, because it won't get you into trouble. TMS9900, that was wierd, I had a 99/4 for my sins in an earlier life, strange beast!

Comment: Itanium also has register windows.

Comment: @MichelBillaud - you do not "have to" save/restore *all* registers doing a context switch, some of the currently popular ABIs do not do so.

Comment: Well, I have currently 243 tasks on my linux computer, mostly sitting idle. How many of them never had a context switch, leading the operating system to save the content of registers?

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Are you thinking "function call" or "context switch"?  Saving all registers on a function call is not productive, but a context switch must save any register that could be in use when the context switch occurs.  There may be some benefits to having a system with an extended register file (accessible via opcode prefix) where each register has an extra "in use" bit, where it's possible to read the "in-use" status of 32 or 64 registers at once, and where a register save/restore only has to process registers that are "in use", but I'm not sure that would be worth the cost.

Comment: @supercat - if you are not planning to use some registers in context-local ways, there's no reason to save them.  Hence, a need to save them is dictated by the ABI chosen, and not a forced cost of having unecessary registers in the hardware.  For example, if you have no plans to use an integrated FPU, there is no reason to save the registers unique to that, even though they are present in the silicon.  ISRs have no need to save registers they will not touch.  And operating system scheduler-type task switches that might be unaware of details tend to be infrequent in computational terms.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I would consider it necessary that asynchronous context switches preserve all registers that could possibly be in use by the code that was running.  Whether that means copying them to memory or simply leaving them undisturbed doesn't alter the semantics when using interrupts that return directly to the previous code.  Any registers that aren't preserved across a stack switch, however, will be essentially useless (a register which is "owned" by a single task and not used by anything else will be preserved across context switches away from and back to that task).

Comment: It is the job of an ABI, *not the hardware* to dictate "all registers that could possibly be in use by the code that was running".  An ABI is a *contract* between modules which governs precisely such things!   Putting a register in hardware does not *force* the ABI to require it to be saved; while programmers or compilers which *violate* the ABI allegedly in use already have plenty of others ways of causing problems.

Comment: @MichelBillaud approximately zero of them.

Comment: @supercat: Actually many architectures have a way for the context switch code to check which sets of extended registers were touched since last saved, which in theory eliminates the cost for lots of apps. But then someone thinks they're clever and makes `memcpy` use all the vector registers....

Comment: @ChrisStratton: While there is some precedent for "you can't use registers X and Y" being considered part of an "ABI" (e.g. k0 and k1 registers on mips), it's unusual usage. Certainly there are unwanted/unsafe covert messaging channels between processes if save/restore of these "ABI-forbidden registers" is not performed at context switch. That is, processes which should not be able to communicate may be able to do so by storing information in the forbidden registers and waiting for context switches.

Comment: *"Registers are tightly bound to the ALU, and can take many roles of data sources, sinks, modifiers etc. They therefore need a wealth of wide multiplexed connections"* Not necessarily so, not all registers are general-purpose and interchangeable. It is perfectly possible to have FP registers, indexing registers, arithmetic registers etc. SPARC, x86, Z80 and others do this.

Answer (score 13):

Registers must be adressed within the instruction. If there are a lot of registers, the instruction is longer. Saving and restoring register content for an interrupt service needs more time if there are a lot of registers.

Answer (score 5):

As most things, the number of registers is a compromise between cost, complexity and usefulness.

Registers are implemented as multi-port static RAM, which makes them more costly (chip area) than other storage options.

Then they are coupled with the instruction set of the processor, increasing the number of registers increases the complexity of the instruction set. So if you want to stay compatible with the instruction set, you can't just increase the number of registers available in the next generation of processors to increase efficiency, the programs wouldn't use them.

Next is how much registers do you really need? There is a limit to their usefulness. Consider you write an algorithm which performs some mathematical operation on 1024 bytes, let's say multiply by 5. With current register counts, you end up with something like:

```
load operand1=5
load address
loop: load operand2=byte1@address
multiply Register1 with Register2
store result
increment address
if address = end goto endLoop
jump loop
endLoop:
```

Now if you would have 1024 registers and all the data stored there, your program would look like:

```
multiply Register1 with Register2
multiply Register1 with Register3
multiply Register1 with Register4
multiply Register1 with Register5
multiply Register1 with Register6
...
```

Because each of them is a different instruction, every single one of them has to be written out. So your needed program memory is exploding. After realizing this, you might want to introduce some instructions like, `multiply register1 with register(2 to 256)`. But when would you stop, do you provide an instruction for all combinations?

So maybe the numbers we currently have available is a fine trade-off between cost, complexity and usefulness.

Comment: I think the program `multiply Register1 with Register2
multiply Register1 with Register3` is very unrealistic as the data must have come directly or indirectly from outside the computer, so the registers need to be loaded, and the results need to be used somewhere, directly or indirectly, so the registers need to stored. In reality, a decent optimising compiler for a high-level language will 'unroll' the loop of the first program to create something like the second program, optimising register use, memory latency, maybe cache occupancy and execution speed.

Comment: There is no need for many special purpose `multiply register1 with register(2 to 256)` instructions. Pipelining improves CPU throughput significantly especially for simpler to decode and execute instructions. So the effect of complex, massive variety instructions can be achieved by using several simpler instructions with a higher execution rate. Having larger numbers of registers helps by allowing the compiler to generate many independent instructions (ones that do not share a register), which can be completed independently, improving throughput. Your example = more registers are better.

Answer (score 5):

Registers are very expensive. VERY expensive. It's not so much the registers themselves, it's all the connections from and to registers. Say you have an instruction reg1 = reg2 + reg3. To implement this *fast*, you need to read data from two registers in one cycle, and write to another register in the second cycle. Now if you have a processor that can execute multiple instructions per cycle, say three instructions, you'd need to be able to read data from six registers each cycle, and write data to 3 registers. That's an awful, awful lot of very fast connections.

Of course you can just use more transistors. The problem is: The speed goes down. You need more hardware to choose from more registers. The space for the register file gets bigger. All that makes things slower. So with the same technology, you might be able to have 16 registers and run at 2,600 MHz or have 32 registers and run at 2,400 MHz. Now the additional registers must make up for a significant drop in clock speed.

Answer (score 3):

> What factor influenced the number of registers

### - [Memory Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy)

Registers, Cache, RAM are all implemented with different storage technologies.

Different technologies differ in

1. Access times
2. Cost
3. Density

An example : The internal registers found in a CPU are [Static Random Access Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory), while the computer main memory is [Dynamic Random Access Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_random-access_memory)

A Static RAM  binary cell is implemented using a 6-transistor circuit while a Dynamic RAM binary cell is implemented using a capacitor and a transistor. Comparing SRAM and DRAM

- SRAM memory is much faster than DRAM memory [Few cycles to access SRAM compared to DRAM]
- SRAM circuit consumes less power than DRAM
- DRAM require refreshing every bit in the memory periodically unlike SRAM
- SRAM costs more than DRAM
- SRAM has a lower density compared to the DRAM

So its not a practical thing to increase the number of the fast, expensive, less density memory. In fact we might use a few of them and a well written program will store the most frequent used data inside these fast registers while the less frequent used data are stored in the slower memory.

### - [Instruction length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set#Instruction_length)

The address of the registers is included within an instruction, which limits the number of the accessible registers based on the numbers of bit that can represent the address. For example in the MIPS architecture the 32-bit length instruction holds only 5-bits to represent the address of the accessible registers which limits the number of the registers to 2<sup>5</sup> = 32 register. Increasing the number of the registers would require increasing the instruction length in order to include sufficient bits that could access all the registers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at a processor's instruction set, there are a number of ways of grouping them. For example, all the `ADD` instructions might be grouped together, and all the `XOR` instructions.

Within each group of the same instruction, there may be versions that operate on memory, or on registers. It's this sub-grouping that effectively defines the number of registers that the processor has.

As an 8-bit hypothetical example, let's say the `$Ax` instructions might be the `ADD` instructions, and `$Cx` might be the `XOR` instructions. With this design, there are only four bits left to define the operands!

- One might have only four general-purpose registers, and use two bits to define one, and two bits to define the other.
- Or, one might use the first bit to distinguish "special" variants, and the other 3 bits to define which of eight registers to operate with the accumulator (`$x0` could be the accumulator itself).
- Or, one could have more than this number of registers - but then limit which registers are accessible to which instructions.

Of course, we're past 8-bit instruction sets. But still, this logic helped define register sets in the past - it will continue to do so into the future.

EDIT (as requested)

Say the top four bits are for the instruction: `ADD`, `SUB`, `XOR`, `MOV`, `CMP` etc. There are 16 possibilities here. Then, for those instructions where register-to-register makes sense (e.g. `ADD Rx,Ry`), you need to specify `Rx` and `Ry`. Say the next two bits are for `x`, and the last two are for `y`. Thus:

```
ADD R1, R2  =>  'ADD' + 'R1' + 'R2' => $A0 + $04 + $02
```

With only two bits to define a register like this, you only have room for a total of four registers!

As an aside, you'll note that some register combinations don't make sense. For example, `MOV Rx, Rx` (does nothing) and `SUB Rx, Rx` (always produces `0`). These could become special-case instructions:

1. `SUB Rx, Rx` could become `NOT Rx` - a single-operand instruction.
2. `MOV Rx, Rx` could become a `MOV` instruction that takes a second byte as an immediate value, interpreted as `MOV Rx, #$yy`.

In this way you can "play" with the instruction map, filling in the holes for otherwise-useless or -nonsensical instructions to provide a larger instruction set for the programmer. But ultimately, the instruction set defines the register set.

Comment: I am still confused, can you explain how only 4bits left for operands?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: IMHO this answer would be significantly improved by moving the "*hypothetical example assumed an 8-bit instruction set*" to the start of the question. I wasted time trying to make sense of it, concluded it only made sense for an 8-bit, fixed length instruction, then read on to find that is the case. IMHO, that sort of instruction set is not very irrelevant in the context of the question; its whole address space could be tightly coupled static RAM. I also think the part beginning "*Some register combinations don't make sense  ...*" is not relevant to the question, and could be deleted. My $0.02

Answer (score -2):

Intel is using thousands of registers nowadays - hundreds per CPU core. But the largest amount of data stored on a CPU is in cache, which indirectly answers the question. Cache is organized in layers, with a small fast L1 cache and slower L2 and L3 caches further away. The register file in a sense is L0, even faster than L1 but also even smaller. So, you could increase the number of registers, but that would likely slow them down.